# Google GTL Objective-C API

Tags: iphone, objective-c, macos, ipad

I have been looking into the Google Objective-c API, there is a small amount around on their old GData API, but now they seem to have dropped that and have new GTL API as they call it.

Tell me if I'm wrong. Looking at it and I can see some thing about calendar and Google Drive APIs etc but nothing YouTube related, are they included?

I need the API to access YouTube.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The YouTube XML API has not yet been replaced by a JSON API.